# Decomposition of inverse covariance matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance, matrix-decomposition

If I have a covariance matrix $\Sigma$, 
and 
$x^T \Sigma^{-1} x = ||Ax||_2^2$. What exactly is the significance of $A$?

I tried solving for $A$ with an eigenvalue decomposition of $\Sigma$ as follows,

$x^T \Sigma^{-1} x = x^T (Q \Lambda Q^T)^{-1}x = 
x^T Q\Lambda^{-1}Q^{-1} x  = x^TA^TAx$
 and this is where I get stuck. I am unable to figure out a closed form solution to $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the entries of the matrix are real, 
$||Ax||_2^2 =<Ax,Ax>$
$  =<x,A^*Ax>$
$=<x,A^TAx>$
$=x^T\Sigma^{-1}x$
$=<x,\Sigma^{-1}x>$

Since I don't have the proof , let me assume that $\Sigma^{-1}$ is positive definite. 
Then we have  $\Sigma^{-1}=A^*A$ and therefore $A$ is the unique nonnegative square root of $\Sigma^{-1}$. 
The algorithm to compute it are given here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Square_roots_of_positive_operators

Comment: But is there a closed formula for $A$ and what is the intuitive meaning of it?

Comment: Since the matrix $Σ^{−1}$ is symmetric, it can be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix $U$( spectral theorem ). Let $Σ^{−1}=UDU^T$. Now, the squareroot can be written as$A=UD^{1/2}U^T$. Regarding intuitive meaning,I don't know much. Actually a better forum for this question would be http://stats.stackexchange.com/